# Previous images stay then slide new image again with jQuery

Tags: jquery, slideshow

**Expected Result:** When a thumbnail is clicked, new main image slide from right to left then stays there - and keeps repeating for every clicked thumbnail.

**Current Result:** Here's my jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/418b90eb/

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.thumbnail-stay a', function() {
    var photo_fullsize =  jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('150/200', '500/500');
    jQuery('.gallery-main-img img').attr('src', photo_fullsize).attr('style', 'right: 0;');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Testing your example, it doesn't do what you're saying it does. Everytime I click a thumbnail it just replaces the picture which is in the slide. It doesn't slide from the left or right. Only slides on the first click of a thumbnail

Comment: Oh sorry, what I mean to say is that, I'm working to make the jsfiddle link to work like my question above because as of now it is really not working.